# Passing function as a parameter

Tags: objective-c, function, parameter-passing

I want to search an array of NSDate, so here what I do:

```
searchResult = CFArrayBSearchValues((CFArrayRef)someDateArray, arrayRange, dateToFind, CFDateCompare, nil);
```

However, I get this warning:

Incompatible pointer types passing 'CFComparisonResult (CFDateRef, CFDateRef, void *)' to parameter of type 'CFComparatorFunction' (aka 'CFComparisonResult (*)(const void *, const void *, void *)')

How do I properly pass a function as a parameter? I think I got my syntax wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the function pointer to the `CFComparatorFunction` type, since it has a more explicit signature (it uses `CFDateRef` instead of `void *`).

```
searchResult = CFArrayBSearchValues((CFArrayRef)someDateArray, arrayRange, dateToFind, (CFComparatorFunction)CFDateCompare, nil);
```